# Por que esse código em c funciona?

Tags: c

Quando chamo a função `malloc`, aloquei o espaço só pra um `char`, mas ele funciona para palavras de qualquer tamanho, por isso fiquei confuso

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *palavra;
    palavra = malloc(sizeof(char));
    printf("Informe a palavra\n");
    scanf("%s", palavra);
    printf ("%d", conta_vogais(palavra));
}

int conta_vogais (char* s){
    int tamanho = strlen(s);
    char *vogais = {"aeiouAEIOU"};
    int i, j, count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(vogais); j++){
            if(s[i] == vogais[j]){
                count++;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Quando você aloca, ele reserva a quantidade na memória do tipo String, sendo que se você digitar apenas uma palavra vai funcionar, agora se você colocar espaço e digitar a segunda palavra não funcionará. Dá uma olha neste link: * Fonte: https://www.ime.usp.br/~elo/IntroducaoComputacao/Caracter.htm

Answer (score 2):

Não querendo satirizar demasiado, começo por dizer isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Você viu o resultado que esperava, mas isso não quer dizer que funcione.**

O código que tem representa **comportamento indefinido** de acordo com o manual do C para qualquer string que seja introduzida, pois tem de reservar sempre pelo menos mais um caratere para o terminador `\0`. Então é como se só tivesse sempre espaço para o terminador.

O que acontece vai depender de inúmeros fatores, mas regra geral toma 3 formas:

1. Nada visivelmente acontece. A sobreposição de memoria não substituiu nada, e embora pareça sorte é na verdade azar pois você não se consegue aperceber do problema.
2. Acede zona de memoria protegida e o programa estoira com um *Segmentation Fault*. Isto é mais normal de acontecer quando a sobreposição é muito grande, como no seu caso se escrever 10 mil ou 100 mil carateres. Este é o melhor cenário pois você apercebe-se rapidamente do problema.
3. Sobrepõe outros valores na memoria sem estoirar. Este cenário é difícil de detetar e gera todo o tipo de comportamentos malucos, pois acaba alterando outras variáveis que tem na mesma função sem que se aperceba. É precisamente neste ponto que os hackers se aproveitam para fazer [ataques de *buffer overflow*](http://www.crimesciberneticos.com/2011/02/entendendo-o-buffer-overflow.html).